# How to tell which subscriber put an event into error queue?

Tags: error-handling, nservicebus

We have multiple subscribers subscribing to the same event. One of them raised exception rarely and put the event into error queue. Is it possible that from the event in error queue, I can tell which subscriber caused the problem? For example, can I get call stack where exception happened in the event sitting in error queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tool like [Queue Explorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/index.php) to have a look at the message headers on the error queue.

With QE all you need to do is open the message you interested in and look at the Extension tab (XML viewer)
This will show you quite a bit of info including the stacktrace and the subscriber address that caused the error.

See below for an example:
[image]

I hope this helps!